# How to have a notification when a user exits the app on a specific screen (or activity)?

Tags: android

I am trying to show a notification to the user when they exit my app on a specific screen (almost like a reminder to complete their booking for e.g.). I am using the following code to create a notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

But I am unsure where to put this code as I do not know how to check whether the home button has been pressed on that specific screen/activity.

Answer (score 0):

You needs global variable or singleton to stre the current activity/screen.

By click on HomeButton you could then check what is active.

In actvity you could set this variable by `onCreate` and `onResume`

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by using the onReceive method (Broadcast Receiver).